# SOAP Response in WCF

Tags: wcf

I have created WCF service. It is working fine but our client want response in some specific form. I have shared 2 responses

[image]

My Code :

```
 [ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]    
    MyClass GetMyData();

// TODO: Add your service operations here
}
```

// Use a data contract as illustrated in the sample below to add composite types to service operations.
    [DataContract]
    public class MyClass
    {
        int _id ;
        string _name ;

```
    [DataMember]
    public int ID
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set { _id = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: why would you do that? `WCF` is supposed to send `SOAP` messages.

Comment: Because our client want response in that format

Comment: What format do they want the response in? Your question is devoid of details.

Comment: Note that WCF 3.5 supports SOAP Envelopes and "plain" XML and JSON responses - in addition to supporting REST (via a hacked-on add-on). If you're using "web"-mode then WCF will automatically render responses as XML or JSON depending on the HTTP `Accept` header as-received from the client.

Comment: WCF was designed to support arbitrary protocols (indeed, TCP support is out-of-the-box) however this process is difficult and WCF is now generally considered an end-of-life platform. Its replacement: ASP.NET Web API, is strictly HTTP+REST-only and does not lend itself well to supporting SOAP or other protocols well at all.

Answer (score 1):

Your "Client Expectation" is a XSD file. They are meant to validate SOAP responses, not to be one.
There are [plenty](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=xsd%20validator&oq=xsd%20validator&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2884j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=xsd%20schema%20validator) of services which can **validate** your XML response based on your XSD.

If you client wants a *XSD response*, maybe you'll have to look for a tool to do that. I think [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(v=vs.110).aspx) might help.